# Has anyone managed to compile Apache HTTP Server on Windows with VS2012?

Tags: apache

Has anyone managed to compile Apache HTTP Server on Windows with VS2012? The solution file does not open in Visual Studio. There were no specific errors, just the Project file is invalid.

Comment: apache.org does not releae binaries, thats why i wanted to build myself. I found out it requires apr, apr-iconv and apr-util. I copied it to the srclib folder. It also requires pcre, which requires CMake to build. I could not build pcre with CMake. That is my current problem.

Comment: I run: nmake /f Makefile.win _apacher, and receive the following error: NMAKE : fatal error U1073: "_apacher" konnte nicht erstellt werden
Stop.

Comment: The right command is: nmake /f Makefile.wiin _buildr